# Oracle Apex - Custom Authorization Scheme

Tags: oracle-apex

I am a beginner to Oracle Apex.

How would I go about creating a custom Authorization scheme?
The process should occur as below:

If the user does not have a certain role in database, a modal form should pop-up for creating an access request for that page.

Essentially, some row should get inserted into some table as a pending record of request.
How do I do this using existing functionalities in oracle apex 19.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would approach it. It doesn't do a redirect to a page, but just rejects you and you can have a separate page elsewhere for requesting authorizations.

Set up an Authorization Scheme and set the page(or pages) to follow that scheme, so they cannot be accessed unless the scheme passes.

Then you set up a table of authorizations with three columns: user, page, date.

And set the authorization scheme to check if user is in the table for that page and the date is either empty or larger than sysdate(authorization has not yet expired).

And you have a page somewhere where people can request authorization for this authorization scheme, you can permit it and write them into the table, along with a date of expiry if their permission is temporary.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd think through the problem.

I need to protect each page, but not necessarily through declarative techniques, because of this requirement you describe - some sort of redirect, instead of a standard message.

I could define something that could check each page load.

Check out slide 62 of this [presentation](https://prezi.com/ddffuuil0p-a/managing-multiple-apex-applications/)

Here I define an applicaiton process that checks a relevantly designed table, and redirects if necessary. I'm not sure if this would also work for a modal page, but you could try it.

You could display a region on the the page you redirect to that facilates the request, maybe as as a button on the alert region.

All these concepts would have existed since I started using 3.x, except the ease of the modal dialog... it's now a matter of defining the appropriate table. Perhaps along the lines of

```
page_auth (
 app_id number not null
,page_id number not null
,app_user varchar2 not null
,requested date not null
,approved date
,approved_by varchar2
,revoked date
,revoked by
)
```

Comment: Thank you Scott for your response. Could you please tell me how to edit the JavaScript code in Oracle Apex?
I know about the JavaScript code option that's available for some components. But where do I get to edit it without having to navigate to the Page Designer?

Comment: There is no need for JS in my described solution, and it really depends on what you're trying to do,